# Map Marker snippet Button is not working

Tags: android, dictionary, marker

I am using Map, In that Marker on click I opened a custom `snippet(InfoWindowAdapter)`, In that layout I has `Textview` and Button. I set text from `marker.getSnippet()`. But the click event is not getting working on Button `onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

Your button `onClick` won't work because `InfoWindow` is not live view. It's rendered as an image, that's why it can't handle typical touch events.

Instead, you can implement `OnInfoWindowClickListener` registered via `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` on your `GoogleMap`.

For more information please see:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows